# How should I understand the "combinatorial property" here?

Tags: machine-learning, pac-learning

I came across the following statement on page 78 of the book [**"Understanding Machine Learning: From Theory to Algorithms"**](https://www.cs.huji.ac.il/~shais/UnderstandingMachineLearning/understanding-machine-learning-theory-algorithms.pdf)

> The fundamental theorem of learning theory characterizes PAC learnability of classes of binary classifiers using VC-dimension. The VC-dimension of a class is a **combinatorial property** that denotes the maximal sample size that can be shattered by the class.

How do you understand the "combinatorial property" in this context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combinatorics is an area of mathematics primarily concerned with counting, both as a means and an end in obtaining results, and certain properties of finite structures. Here VC-dimension is the maximum size of the sets that can be shattered by a hypothesis class. So VC-dimension can be called a combinatorial property.

Here is my reference from [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorics).

Comment: The combinatorial property here refers to how many sample data do I need in order to produce all possible combinations of arrangement that can be shattered by the hypothesis class. In other words if observe coin flips how many of those do I need to observe so that on average I can tell whether the coin will land head or tails.

Comment: In simple terms the combinatorial property here refers to all possible combinations of concepts that could exist. Let's be more concrete with a simple example. Suppose we are doing binary classification then the outcome can be either positive or negative. If we have m samples then all possible concepts (a.k.a labelings) amount to $2^{m}$ since we only have 2 possible outputs from the classifier $\{+1, -1\}$ and $m$ samples, hence there are $2^{m}$ possible ways to shatter the class of $\mathcal{H}$, where $\mathcal{H}$ denotes binary classifiers (a.k.a. boolean functions)